# MFC, Unicode and DDX_Text

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, mfc

[UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) makes a strong case to shun the Microsoft `TCHAR`, `_T()`, `LPCTSTR` and so forth completely, to push `wchar_t` aside as well, and bravely embrace a world of UTF-8 strings based on a narrow `char` type.

Which seemed fine until I came to the MFC `DDX_Text()` macro for getting a `CString` both in and out of an edit control. Is there any reasonable way to:

- Declare `CStringA myString` intended as an UTF-8 string (or as an ASCII/ANSI string as a degenerate case)
- Compile with `UNICODE` defined
- Pass `myString` through suitable conversions and/or temporary variables and into the third parameter to `DDX_Text()`, and get sensible results to and from the associated edit control?

If not, how would you recommend handling string input/output via edit controls if your application wanted to use UTF-8 (or ASCII/ANSI in the degenerate case)?

(P.S. this is motivated by Visual Studio 2013 encouraging Unicode-only use of MFC. Given an MFC app, and a desire to use VS2013, this requires `UNICODE` to be defined... or to cling on to a deprecated way of doing things.)

Answer (score 2):

Windows internally uses UTF-16 as UNICODE standard. So you will have to follow that and use CString which is defined as CStringW in UNICODE. Also you have to use _T() macro. All Windows common controls like Edit Box, List Box, etc are using UNICODE as well.

I'd suggest using UTF-8 for networking stuff only.

// UTF8 conversion

```
CStringA CUtility::UTF16toUTF8(const CStringW& utf16)
{
    return CW2A(utf16, CP_UTF8);
}

CStringW CUtility::UTF8toUTF16(const CStringA& utf8)
{
    return CA2W(utf8, CP_UTF8);
}
```